# Sort fields in a Linux file based on the highest to lowest

Tags: linux, sorting

I have a file in which 3 fields are present.

Field 1 has names, field 2 and 3 has numeric values. I need to sort all the fields based on the highest values present in it.

File1.txt

```
ASANSOL 16.76   31.991
ASANSOL 16.72   33.687
ASANSOL 16.48   25.344
ASANSOL 16.74   30.777
BANGALORE   13.39   17.243
BANGALORE   14.34   20.852
BANGALORE   15.58   25.112
BANGALORE   14.59   34.752
BANGALORE   17.93   2.792
BHOPAL  16.53   13.487
BHOPAL  16.7    11.599
BHOPAL  16.65   16.003
BHOPAL  16.87   20.674
```

After sorting and taking unique values, the desired output should produce as below:

```
ASANSOL     16.76   33.687
BANGALORE   17.93   34.752
BHOPAL      16.87   20.674
```

Help me how shall I go about this? #Script would be preferable

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I made an answer of not asked first. The right answer is simpler:

```
awk '{ d1[$1] = $2; d2[$1] = $3 } END { for(x in d1) print x, d1[x], d2[x] }' <filename>
```

----------- Old answer -----------------

simple answer is:

```
cat <filename> | awk '{ if($2>$3) { max = $2 } else { max = $3 } print max, $0 }' | sort -r | sed 's/^[0-9.]* //'
```

1. find max number using awk and prepend it to every line;
2. sort;
3. remove first column using sed

Comment: to be precise, i m not comparing field 2 & 3. It something like:

I need the highest value of 2nd filed for Asansol, which is 16.76
and same with 3rd filed, I need the highest value of 3rd filed for Asansol, which is 33.687.

-All together it should print one line for Asanasol: ASANSOL     16.76   33.687

Answer (score -1):

if you don't want to write a small script to handle this, you can use awk to do your sorting:
http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html

Comment: actually I was looking forward for a script itself. :)